# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths do nothing

Tags: objective-c

I need to change the text's cell when the device rotate. This is my code:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{

[self.lista beginUpdates];
NSIndexPath *durPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:durPath, nil];

UITableViewCell *celda = [self.lista cellForRowAtIndexPath:
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
celda.textLabel.text = @"new text for the cell";

[self.lista reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.lista endUpdates];

}
```

and nothing happens. What's wrong?